# asp.net RequiredFieldValidator with custom control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have custom control with asp textbox inside.

And i need to Validate by RequiredFieldValidator my custom control on CLIENT side.

I added attribute to custom control class:

```
[ValidationProperty("Text")]
    public class WatermarkTextBox : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
}
```

It looks like working but it always make submit to server. How can i check it only on client side?

Comment: it shouldn't go to the server. Could you paste the relevant pieces of the ASPX?

Comment: I think this changed in more recent versions of asp.net.  If you add the ValidationProperty as described in the question, and in the html the *first* input field in your usercontrol is the one with the value to validate, then client-side validation works magically without any additional work required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a CustomValidator like this

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateCheckBox"
ErrorMessage="Please enter something.">
```

ClientValidationFunction is the name of your javascript function

Comment: I write about RequiredFieldValidator not about CustomValidator

And to use it on client side with custom control we need add attribute ValidationProperty and to ControlToValidate set IdOfControl:IdOfTextbox

Comment: I know what you wrote about.  You can't use the RequiredFieldValidator.  You *must* use a CustomValidator.